# C# Websockets - TCP Reverse proxy displaying websocket error

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, proxy, reverse-proxy

Okay so I made a C# TCP reverse proxy server, and for some reason, other TCP reverse proxy servers work but mine does it. In the developer console, mine displays:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1738/' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1
```

Here's the code:

Socket.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MINA
{
    class Sock
    {
        Socket Client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        string name = null;
        public Sock(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void Connect(string IP, int port, Socket c = null)
        {
            this.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 0;
            if(c != null)
            {
                this.Client = c;
                return;
            }
            this.Client.Connect(IP, port);
            Output.Write("Connected to " + IP + ':' + port, name);
        }

        public string Send(string data, bool recv = true)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
                Output.Write(data, name + " | send");
                if(recv)
                {
                    return this.Receive();
                } else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            } catch(SocketException)
            {
                Output.Write("Socket client might not be able to connect to host, and therefore can not send any data.", "fail");
                this.Client.Close();
                return null;
            }
        }
        public bool isConnected = true;
        public string Receive()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                this.Client.Receive(buffer);
                string Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", "");
                Output.Write(Data, name + " | recv");
                return Data;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                isConnected = false;
                this.Client.Close();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            this.Client.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

SocketServer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace MINA
{
    class SocketServer
    {
        int BindPort = 0;
        Socket Server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        public SocketServer(int BindPort = 443)
        {
            this.BindPort = BindPort;
        }

        public void BindListen()
        {
            this.Server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.BindPort));
            Output.Write("Server bound to port " + this.BindPort, "server");
            this.Server.Listen(1000);
            Output.Write("Server listening for new connections", "server");
            while (true)
            {
                Socket RCV = this.Server.Accept();
                Thread t = new Thread(
                    new ThreadStart(
                        delegate
                        {
                            Output.Write("Client accepted, bombs fired.", "server");
                            Sock Receiver = new Sock("RECEIVER");
                            Receiver.Connect("0", 0, RCV);



                            Sock Forwarder = new Sock("FORWARDER");
                            Forwarder.Connect("127.0.0.1", 443);
                            while (Forwarder.isConnected && Receiver.isConnected)
                            {
                                handleReceiverReceive(Forwarder, Receiver);
                                handleForwarderReceive(Forwarder, Receiver);
                            }
                            Forwarder.Close();
                            Receiver.Close();
                        }
                    )
                );
                t.Start();
            }
        }

        private void handleForwarderReceive(Sock Forwarder, Sock Receiver)
        {
            string forwarderReceive = Forwarder.Receive();
            if (forwarderReceive != null)
            {
                Receiver.Send(forwarderReceive, false);
            }
            else
            {
                Forwarder.Close();
                Receiver.Close();
            }
        }

        private void handleReceiverReceive(Sock Forwarder, Sock Receiver)
        {
            string receiverReceive = Receiver.Receive();
            if (receiverReceive != null)
            {
                Forwarder.Send(receiverReceive, false);
            }
            else
            {
                Forwarder.Close();
                Receiver.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to compare working server with non-working server.  Usually issues are the html headers.  You may need to add some headers to get it to work.

Comment: the headers are automatically supplied by the client itself.

Comment: Which means they're universal for both the working and broken servers

Comment: You never should connect to the loopback address 127.0.0.1.  You can listen to this address and return messages to the loopback connection, but never connected to the address.  A connection should always be to a remote IP.  You are using port 443 (SSL/TTL).  There are some good examples of SSL/TTL at website www.codeproject.com that you can use for reference.